QPrintPreviewDialog genera una autonumeración por defecto, Cuando le soy estructura a la pagina no me muestra la previsualización del contenido
Hice una pregunta cuando el QPrintPreviewDialog genera autonumeración, como hago para que un usuario dese on o ponerla que parámetro controla eso, se me fue explicado que es por el formato de la pagina, y que debido a eso la case autoenumeraba la previzualización
El siguiente codigo aprenta arreglar el problema
from PyQt5 import QtCore

...
paper_size = QtCore.QSizeF()
paper_size.setWidth(printer.width())
paper_size.setHeight(printer.height())
document.setPageSize(paper_size)
document.print_(self.printer)
En PyQt6 también podrías hacer algo como:

document.setPageSize(printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Unit.Point).size())
document.print(self.printer)

sin embargo al momento de escribir contenido este no es previzualizado y quisiera que los usuarios pudieran escojer si ennumerar las paginas o no entonces tengo bastantes dudas no se si alguien me las puede aclarar.
Agradezco su atención

Este es mi código
  def prin_preview(self):
    """
    This funciton create a window that allows to the customer customize his page size
    :return: QPrinter
    """
    self.preview_page_dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog()
    self.preview_page_dialog.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Icons/Main_logo.png"))
    self.preview_page_dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.prepare_the_document_to_visualize)
    self.preview_page_dialog.exec_()


def prepare_the_document_to_visualize(self,printer: QPrinter):
    self.printer = printer
    self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - " + str(self.current_tab_info.name))
    self.document = self.current_plain_text_widget.document()
    self.document.setPageSize(printer.pageRect(QPrinter.Unit.Point).size())
    print(self.document.pageSize())
    self.document.print_(self.printer)


def print_document(self):

    self.printer = QPrinter()

    dialog_printer = QPrintDialog(self.printer)
    if dialog_printer.exec_():

        self.printer.setDocName(f"{self.windowTitle()} - " + str(self.current_tab_info.name))
        self.document = self.current_plain_text_widget.document()
        self.document.print_(self.printer)

